# Having null in a value of a ListResourceBundle implementation

Tags: java, io, resourcebundle

In a ListResourceBundle implementation I define an array with some keys containing null values. 
It compiles fine the loading process of the bundle containing a null value. However when I call getObject on a key with a non-null value (like in the following example "Pollution" which has value "high"), it gives me a NullPointerException.

Do you have an idea why it happens in that way?

```
ResourceBundle labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundlething", new Locale("it"));
labels.getObject("Pollution");// here NullPointerException, However Pollution has a \n
```

value, other keys of the same array do not.

UPDATE: 
This is the stacktrace I receive:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   java.util.ListResourceBundle.loadLookup(ListResourceBundle.java:196)
>   at
>   java.util.ListResourceBundle.handleGetObject(ListResourceBundle.java:124)
>   at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:387) at
>   ResourceBundleThing.main(ResourceBundleThing.java:38)

and this is the bundle I load by passing new `Locale("it")` as target `Locale`:

```
import java.util.ListResourceBundle;
public class bundlething_it extends ListResourceBundle {

    private  Object [][] contents  ={{"Inhabitants",null},{"Pollution",new Double(3.4034)},{"Lollerball",new Integer(132)}};
    public Object[][] getContents()
    {
        return contents;
    }
```

}

There is null corresponding to "Inhabitans" however I am referring only to "Pollution" which has a non-null value. Still I get a NullPointerException; If I remove that null from "Inhabitants" it works.. so it's there the problem, I know. However I would like to know why since I am not using that particular key-value pair.
Does it load all the values as soon as getObject it's called?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Come on Rollerball. You have posted 231 questions already, and you still haven't understood that you should always paste the stack trace of the exception and the relevant code?

Comment: @JBNizet As I wrote in the question it's a NullPointerException which is signalized at the exact same position where I wrote it does.

Comment: Then labels is null, which means you're not showing us the real code, since ResourceBundle.getBundle() doesn't return null. Why don't you show us the real code, and the complete stack trace?

Comment: @JBNizet Lables is not null since I am able to getLocale from it and it returns "it". However I will update the code asap with the ListResourceBundle implementation if helps

Comment: Then the NullPointerException isn't thrown by this line. Paste this stack trace. Stack traces don't lie.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.ListResourceBundle.loadLookup(ListResourceBundle.java:196)
 at java.util.ListResourceBundle.handleGetObject(ListResourceBundle.java:124)
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:387)
 at ResourceBundleThing.main(ResourceBundleThing.java:38)

Comment: @JBNizet check out my update in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace precisely indicates where the error comes from:

```
    Object[][] contents = getContents();
    HashMap<String,Object> temp = new HashMap<>(contents.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < contents.length; ++i) {
        // key must be non-null String, value must be non-null
        String key = (String) contents[i][0];
        Object value = contents[i][1];
        if (key == null || value == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException(); // <-- HERE
        }
        temp.put(key, value);
    }
```

So, you have your answer: although I haven't seen it mentioned in the documentation, `ListResourceBundle` doesn't allow null values.